# Gross-Pitaevskii equation and Bogoliubov approach

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

I have a dilute weakly-interacting bose gas and make the assumption that I have only s-wave scattering. Then I'm able to write the Hamiltonian as:

$$
H=\sum\frac{p^2}{2m}a_p^{\dagger}a_p+\frac{1}{2V}V_0\sum a_{p_1+q}^{\dagger}a_{p_2-q}^{\dagger}a_{p_1}a_{p_2}
$$

Now, I can use Bogoliubov's approach and replace $a_0$ with a c-number. When I do this to second order, I will receive the Bogoliubov dispersion law.

My question is now, how does this refer to the Gross-Pitaevskii equation? What are the differences and similarities? Do they both belong togehter?

Comment: For an interesting and lucid review of the relationship between these two approximations, see [Leggett, New J. Phys. **5**, 103 (2003)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/5/1/103/meta;jsessionid=B7B09FBCA7FE9CC334A952741E66BA6A.c2.iopscience.cld.iop.org).

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look on this one. Since it's from Leggett, it will be probable useful. :-)

Comment: I would be also happy about hearing some intuitions :-)

Comment: The Gross-Pitaevskii's equation is obtained from the Heisenberg equations-of-motion for the normal and anomalous bosonic Green's functions in the ordered (superfluid) phase. For a detailed account, see Chp. 14, section 55 of Fetter, A. L., and J. D. Walecka. “Quantum theory of many-particle systems” (1971).